# What's the property does the inequality about supremum use?

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

What's the property used in the inequality $ \sup\{x+y | x \in X, y \in Y \} \leq \sup \{ x | x \in X\} + \sup\{y | y \in Y \}$?
I know it's about Triangle inequality, but I don't know for the exact name of the property.

Comment: It's a corollary of the theorem that says that sup of the sum over a product of sets is the sum of the sups. I don't think it has a name.

Comment: It follows from the theorem about summation and inequality: if $a \le x$ and $b \le y$, then $a + b \le x + y$. Though in fact, you can replace $\le$ with $=$ in your statement and still get a true result. For if $(\sup X) - x < \epsilon/2$ and $(\sup Y) - y < \epsilon/2$, then $(\sup X + \sup Y) - (x+y) < \epsilon$.

Comment: By the way, on notation: The set $\{x\mid x\in X\}$ is just a long-winded (and pointless) way of saying the set $X$. They are the same set.